# Database not updating on "Get" PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page a query that will set a table to 0 or 1. Setting to 1 is working, but it will not set back to 0. This is a snippet of the code so far. Can anyone see what's wrong?

page:

```
<p><? if($_SESSION['user_level'] >= GUARDIAN_LEVEL) { if ($row_settings['profile_list'] == 0) {?> 
                    <a onclick='$.get("dos.php",{ cmd: "sprofile", setp:$("1").val(),id: "<?php echo $row_settings['id']; ?>" } ,function(data){ $("#msgp").html(data); });' href="javascript:void(0);">List</a>
                <?php } else if ($row_settings['profile_list'] == 1) {?>
                    <a onclick='$.get("dos.php",{ cmd: "sprofile", setp:$("0").val(),id: "<?php echo $row_settings['id']; ?>" } ,function(data){ $("#msgp").html(data); });' href="javascript:void(0);">Unlist</a>
                <?php } else {echo "N/A";}} else {echo "N/A";} ?></p>
```

update code:

```
if($get['cmd'] == 'sprofile')
{
mysql_query("update users set profile_list='$get[setp]' where id='$get[id]'");
echo "Profile Listing Changed";
//header("Location: $ret");  
// exit();
}
```

**EDIT**

Update Code:

```
if($_GET['cmd'] == 'sprofile')
{
$set = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['setp']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
mysql_query("update users set profile_list='" . $set . "' where id='" . $id . "'");
echo "Profile Listing Changed";
//header("Location: $ret");  
// exit();
}
```

This will set it to 0 and display the right code, but will not set back to 1 for some reason.

Comment: Other than the **massive** design flaw of performing destructive operations on GET?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setp:$("1").val()` needs to be changed to `setp: "1"` as it's not supposed to pulling the value from anywhere

Also changing `$get` to `$_GET` works

Answer (score 2):

It is `$_GET` and not `$get`.

And please atleast use

```
$param = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['your_param_which_goes_to_building_mysql_query']);
$param2 = //similar..
$query = "update users set profile_list='$param1' where id='$param2'"
```

Or better yet, use [prepared statements.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: May be `$get` is custom array! @dpDesignz : what is $get?

Comment: I considered that, but it possible otherwise too. May be he meant (and there is a good possibility of it being) HTTP/GET. Both ways, OP must update his post with proper explanations.

Comment: Thanks. I never knew there was a difference with the $get and $_GET. :). Please see edited code though. Still not working. Will change to 0, but not back again.

Comment: What do you mean by change back to zero? Do you pass the parameters via forms (or any other means) properly?

Comment: @Thrustmaster I'm using it as a boolean. If 0 then do this, if 1 then do this. So when I click the button, it either changes it to 0 or 1, depending on what it already is. Now if it's 1, it will change to 0 ok, but if it's 0 it doesn't change back to 1.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. It depends on how exactly you are passing `setp` via the form. You should post some more (relevant) code, including the HTML of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Update code:

1. Use `$_GET` instead of `$get` (1st & 3rd line)
2. Use this line as 1st line:

   ```
   if ($_GET['cmd'] == 'sprofile')
   ```
3. Use this line for your mysql_query in the 3rd line:

   ```
   mysql_query("update users set profile_list='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['setp']) . "' where id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "';");
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I never got the escape before but I do now. :). Please see edited code though. Still not working. Will change to 0, but not back again.